# Templates MVC 3 Not working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I just installed visual studio 2010, with MVC3 razor templates, but when I open the template, all the letters appear in bold, as if it were plain text, could someone help me solve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ready, I could do it, I followed the steps of this page:

https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/installing-asp-net-mvc3-on-visual-studio-2010-sp1/

and I installed the following components :[image]

and rebooted my computer, it worked perfect